# Is there a reason not to use array_agg for populating collections?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have the following class:

```java
class Demo {
  private Integer id;
  private Collection<String> tags;
  //...
}
```

And then I have two tables:

```
 Demo         Tags
 id          demoId | name
------       -------+-------
 1             1    |   a
 2             1    |   b
               2    |   c
```

And now I want to select all Demo objects from the DB, I could do:

```sql
select Demo.id,Tags.name
from Demo
left join Tags on (Demo.id=Tabs.demoId)
```

and then I could loop through the result, finding the demo object for the id (creating it if it does not exist) and add the tag for the id.

OR I could just use:

```sql
select Demo.id,array_agg(Tags.name)
from Demo
left join Tags on (Demo.id=Tabs.demoId)
group by Demo.id
```

and the whole thing gets a lot of simpler, because now I have my id/array pairs directly together. The array comes out of JDBC as an array and... Well. You got the point. It's easy and especially it is easier than the previously described method.

However for some reason something tells me that this does not entirely fit in with the concept of SQL and I am suspicious that this method has some drawbacks that I miss.

So the question is: **Are there any reasons (besides portability) not to use array_agg & group by to populate collection fields of objects?**

Answer (score 0):

One reason, mainly: `array_agg()`/`group by` will make the DB do work that can just as well be done in the application, and it's usually easier and cheaper to add new app servers.

The yet more efficient way to do it when you're paginating small result sets, btw, would be to fetch:

```
select Demo.*
from Demo
where …
```

And then, in a separate step:

```
select Tags.demoId,Tags.name
from Tags
where Tabs.demoId in (…)
```

Doing so allows to cache the first query result if applicable using memcached, avoiding a DB query in the process, as well the lists of IDs involved in the second query to avoid further DB work, while allowing for relatively trivial cache invalidation.

Pseudocode:

```
uncached_ids = []
for demo in demos:
  if cached demo.id:
    fetch tags for demo.id
  else:
    uncached_ids[] = id
fetch tags for uncached_ids...
```